# search contacts by name something goes wrong

Tags: java, android, contacts

I am trying to make an speech assistant app. I am using wit.ai's  `SpeechRecognizer` and `RecognitionListener`. When user says call a name, I want to call the specific contact if exist. For achieving this i search in contacts with this method.

```
public  String getPhoneNumber(Context context,String query) {
    String  name=null;

    Cursor cur;
    ContentResolver cr = context.getContentResolver();

    String[] mProjection = {ContactsContract.Contacts._ID,
            ContactsContract.Contacts.LOOKUP_KEY,
            ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER,
            ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME};

    Uri uri = ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI;

    String selection = ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME_PRIMARY + " LIKE ?";
    String[] selectionArgs = new String[]{"%"+query+"%"};

    cur = cr.query(uri, mProjection, selection, selectionArgs, null);
    while (cur != null && cur.moveToNext()) {

       name = cur.getString(
                cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
    }
    if (cur != null) {
        cur.close();
    }



    return name;
}
```

The method always returns `null` ! I am sure that I am doing something wrong but not sure where is the problem. Please Help

Answer (score 2):

When you query your request to Content Resolver you just need **Uri** and **projection** for Cursor and set all the parameter is null, have look :

```
Uri uri = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI;
String[] projection    = new String[] 
{
ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME,
ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER};

Cursor people = getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, null, null, null);

int indexName = 
people.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME);
int indexNumber = 
people.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER);

if(people.moveToFirst()) {
do {
    String name   = people.getString(indexName);
    String number = people.getString(indexNumber);
    // Do work...
} while (people.moveToNext());
}
```

Happy Coding!!

Answer (score 1):

First of all, check that you are [checking permissions at runtime](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html) for android >= 6.0 and the permission is not only in the manifest.

Also your method is called *getPhoneNumber* but is returning the name of the contact, something must be wrong.
If you want the phone number you should change the code inside the while whereas if you are passing a phone number to get the contact's name the *selection* string should change to check the HAS_PHONE_NUMBER instead.

Another thing you could do is changing the selection string to also check the DISPLAY_NAME:

```
String selection = ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME_PRIMARY + " LIKE ?"
    + " OR " + ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME + " LIKE ?";
```